# Where to use Usestate hook in react component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use UseState hook in react but I am not sure where to define it. I tried to declare it in React component but compiler gives an error

```html
class VoiceCallComponent extends React.Component {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(7);
  
  ..
  ..
  ..
}
```

Above code throws an error saying identifier requires.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `useState` in a class component. You need a functional component.

Here is the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Here is the code for your example :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function VoiceCallComponent() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(7);

  // rest of the component logic goes here
  return (
    // JSX
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be alternative option if I want to keep class component?

Comment: This would be the equivalent : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#equivalent-class-example